# TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.postMessage

Tags: javascript

I am learning about the web worker. I am using the follow tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

So far, it works. I have the following code

```
var worker = new Worker('thing.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    alert("Worker said: " +  e.data);
}, false);

worker.postMessage("Test me");
```

and in my thing.js file

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

The above works fine.

However, I need to pass a message from within my thing.js back to my main js file, to demonstrate it passing back a progress update.

Again, the tutorial shows I can do this, so I have the following updated code

```
var worker = new Worker('thing.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    alert("Worker said: " +  e.data);
}, false);

worker.postMessage("Test me");
```

and in my thing.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);

function DoThisThing() {
    postMessage("I should ALSO be working but I am not.");
}
```

This fails with an error message (in FireBug):

> TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.postMessage.

I can't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: You commented out the window message that triggers the worker's message, which seems to just echo the original message.

Comment: try adding target origin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: @kennebec, apologies, that was a mistake in my post, it's now corrected

Comment: @akonsu, how words though? What is the origin? This site is running locally, so I can't use www. or localhost. and I'm not alllowed to do c:\

Comment: maybe `'*'` for anything. it must have an origin. running script from a local file without a web server is inadequate.

Comment: @akonsu, there is no web server. It's more of an application than a website, it just happens to be a website (ie, using HTML as GUI and browser as container) but, its an offline application. I have tried using `*` and same issue persists

Comment: you now have two parameters to the method and it still shows an error saying "not enough"?

Comment: I do still get the error message @akonsu, but, it in a different place. Now the exception occurs in `self.postMessage(e.data);` If I also add the * to this, I get a new error of `TypeError: Argument 2 of DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.postMessage can't be converted to a sequence.`

Comment: Where is DoThisThing() being called inside your worker ?

Answer (score 3):

It would be convenient to have the full source code that triggered the issue, but I bet the problem was that besides instantiating the worker your code was also including the worker file via a script tag. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="thing.js"></script>
```

So basically what you have is:

**thing.js** (worker)

```
   self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      self.postMessage(e.data);
    }, false);

    function DoThisThing() {
        postMessage("I should ALSO be working but I am not.");
    }

    DoThisThing();
```

I assume you were calling DoThisThing() because otherwise you won't get the `"TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.postMessage"` error.

If you run the code as it is it works, but you're also seeing the error.

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.postMessage.
Worker said: I should ALSO be working but I am not.  
Worker said: Test me
```

So what was triggering the TypeError: Not enough arguments...? If you were sourcing the file from a `script` tag, the function gets executed two times actually. On the first call, there's an error.

When `thing.js` gets sourced by the script tag, `DoThisThing()` gets executed. That's the first call. `DoThisThing()` calls `postmessage` (same as `self.postmessage`). But this call gets resolved to `window.postmessage`. This method requires a second argument (`targetOrigin`).

However when the worker gets executed, the call to `postmessage` (same as `self.postmessage`) gets resolved to `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.postmessage`. This method doesn't require a second argument.

When you added a second argument to postmessage, you solved the issue for the first call but not the second. Thus you got a new error: "*TypeError: Argument 2 of DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.postMessage can't be converted to a sequence*".

Summarizing, there are two types of postmessages, one that belongs to the window object and another one that belongs to the `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope` object. A simple call to `postmessage` gets normally resolved by the `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope` object. This call is convenient to communicate workers with their parent. `window.postmessage` requires a second parameter specifying the `targetOrigin`. This call is convenient for cross-origin communications.

In your case, the likely cause of the issue was sourcing the worker JavaScript file from a `script` tag. That caused `postmessage` to get resolved by window, which required a second argument.

Comment: Safari is throwing this error even though it works fine for Chrome and firefox.